# How do I handle user authentication rejection in Google Sign-In?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

If user accepts to use his Google account for authentication, global function specified in `data-onsuccess` is called. That is clear from documentation.

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

Can I get any feedback if user rejected the prompt, e.g. pressed "No" or closed the popup window?

I'm using literally the following code: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

*UPDATE:*

I've found a workaround, the trick is to generate button with javascript: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

There is a documented method `onFailure` in the link above

Comment: Think you forgot to add some code into your question.

Comment: @skobaljic thanks. I should have extended the question and explain the background. Updated the question

Comment: I'll go and check if `data-onfailure` works, although I cannot find where it's documented. Even it works google can remove it if it's not defined in the docs.